# Sum of sinusoids (Fourier decomposition)

Tags: matlab, waveform

Does anyone know how I can recreate a plot like this using matlab? Have been browsing but can't really find much on the topic. 
I pretty much want to take a non-sinusoidal, but periodic waveform and decompose it and plot it in this manner as a sort of proof of concept that a periodic waveform can be decomposed using fourier analysis.[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wrong forum, try Stackoverflow. (If you are brave you can also try Latex. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic functionality of `plot3`:

```
t = 0:0.1:100;
s1 = sin(t1);
f1 = ones(1, 1001);
plot3(t1, s1, f1);
hold on % put the same plot on the same figure
s2 = sin(t/2);
f2 = ones(1, 1001)*2;
plot3(t2, s2, f2);
```